# insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost

Tags: ethereum

```
Running deploy script for the Greeter contract
implementation deploy fee: 0.00495816775eth
deploying from wallet: 0x23BD0EefC73b68f8C47D66F1e94a4dea5d90f8EA
========= NOTICE =========
Request-Rate Exceeded  (this message will not be repeated)

The default API keys for each service are provided as a highly-throttled,    
community resource for low-traffic projects and early prototyping.

While your application will continue to function, we highly recommended      
signing up for your own API keys to improve performance, increase your       
request rate/limit and enable other perks, such as metrics and advanced APIs.

For more details: https://docs.ethers.io/api-keys/
==========================
An unexpected error occurred:

Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS ] (method="estimateGas", transaction={"from":"0x23BD0EefC73b68f8C47D66F1e94a4dea5d90f8EA","maxPriorityFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x59682f00"},"maxFeePerGas":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x067537d20f"},"to":"0x32400084C286CF3E17e7B677ea9583e60a000324","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x24af022a5961c4"},"data":"0xeb67241900000000000000000000000023bd0eefc73b68f8c47d66f1e94a4dea5d90f8ea00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000233adac6f37b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a97e60000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000320000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000023bd0eefc73b68f8c47d66f1e94a4dea5d90f8ea00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","type":2,"accessList":null}, code=INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS, version=providers/5.7.2)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\Envy\Desktop\HELLO-ZKSYNC\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\Envy\Desktop\HELLO-ZKSYNC\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
    at C:\Users\Envy\Desktop\HELLO-ZKSYNC\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\fallback-provider.ts:632:24
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Envy\Desktop\HELLO-ZKSYNC\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\src.ts\fallback-provider.ts:614:33
    at step (C:\Users\Envy\Desktop\HELLO-ZKSYNC\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\fallback-provider.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\Envy\Desktop\HELLO-ZKSYNC\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\fallback-provider.js:29:53)
    at step (C:\Users\Envy\Desktop\HELLO-ZKSYNC\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\fallback-provider.js:33:139)
    at Object.next (C:\Users\Envy\Desktop\HELLO-ZKSYNC\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\fallback-provider.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\Envy\Desktop\HELLO-ZKSYNC\node_modules\@ethersproject\providers\lib\fallback-provider.js:20:58) {
  reason: 'insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost',
  code: 'INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS',
  method: 'estimateGas',
  transaction: {
    from: '0x23BD0EefC73b68f8C47D66F1e94a4dea5d90f8EA',
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x59682f00', _isBigNumber: true },
    maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { _hex: '0x067537d20f', _isBigNumber: true },
    to: '0x32400084C286CF3E17e7B677ea9583e60a000324',
    value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x24af022a5961c4', _isBigNumber: true },
    data: '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',
    type: 2,
    accessList: null
```

Im try deploy some zksync contract but in return is always this error . im sure i have enough fund to deploy and i deploy in correct mainet where my fund are . anyone know what cause this anoying error